# convert to rgb image from 3 3D matrices in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, rgb

I have a converted a rgb image to a grayscale image,then I have retrieved R, G, B channels seperatly in 3 3D matrices..is there any way to concatenate these 3 3D matrices(R,G,B) to obtain a single RGB image in matlab?

#### EDIT

sample code (added from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419621/convert-to-rgb-image-from-3-3d-matrices-in-matlab?noredirect=1#comment23545165_16419621)):

let `I` be the rgb image

```
gr=rgb2gray(I); 
blank = zeros(size(gr),'uint8'); 
r = cat(3,gr,blank,blank); 
g = cat(3,blank,gr,blank); 
b = cat(3,blank,blank,gr); 
imshow(r); 
figure(2),imshow(g); 
figure(3),imshow(b);
```

Comment: you're questions are phrased in a very vague manner. Please provide EXTREMELY SHORT code samples of what you have done and what you are expecting to get.

Comment: after converting rgb to grayscale image I have retrieved R, G, B channels seperatly from that grayscale image in 3 3D matrices seperatly..now I want to combine these 3 3D matrices to get back the original rgb image..is there any way to do this in matlab?

Comment: If you converted RGB image to gray (3D to 2D) how did you recover RGB channels from the 2D gray image?? If you have a miraculous algorithm that retrieve RGB from gray image please do sent it to me!

Comment: let 'i' be the rgb image


gr=rgb2gray(i);
blank = zeros(size(gr),'uint8');
r = cat(3,gr,blank,blank);
g = cat(3,blank,gr,blank);
b = cat(3,blank,blank,gr);
imshow(r);
figure(2),imshow(g);
figure(3),imshow(b);

Answer (score 0):

Converting RGB image into gray one (`gr = rgb2gray(I)`) you LOST a lot of information.
There is no (trivial) way to go back from `gr` image to the original RGB `I`.
The images `r` `g` and `b` you created has no "extra" information apart from `gr` to help you recover the original `I`.

What you can do instead is

```
r = 0*I;
r(:,:,1) = I(:,:,1); % take only red channel to r
g = 0*I;
g(:,:,2) = I(:,:,2);
b = 0*I;
b(:,:,3) = I(:,:,3);
figure;
subplot(131);imshow(r);title('red channel');
subplot(132);imshow(g);title('green channel');
subplot(132);imshow(b);title('blue channel');

% recovering I
recover = cat(3, r(:,:,1), g(:,:,2), b(:,:,3) );
figure;
imshow( recover ); title('recovered RGB image');
```

Comment: no this doesn't solve my problem..
Can u suggest me a way using colormap to convert a grayscale image back to original RGB image?

Comment: I am working on steganography where I hide a rgb image by coverting it into grayscale image..later on after decoding I am able to get grayscale image but I am unable to convert it back to rgb image..

encoding n decoding are 2 different files..so is there any way to store colormap or something else during encoding n then using that stored value while decoding

Answer (score 0):

Since Matlab's rgb2gray uses rgb2ntsc to extract the grayscale information ([source](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/converting-color-data-between-color-spaces.html)), you could use rgb2ntsc instead of rgb2gray and separate out the grayscale image, somehow storing the other two channels to use later to reconstruct (using ntsc2rgb).

```
I2 = rgb2ntsc(I);  %I2 and I are both n x m x 3 images
gr = I2(:,:,1); % now gr is your n x m grayscale image
notgr = I2(:,:,2:3); % these are required to reconstruct image later
```